# Encoding problem in DOMDocument in php

Tags: php, encoding, domdocument, html-entities

When you do this:

```
$d = new DOMDocument();
$e = new DOMElement('myelement', 'hi &nbsp; bye');
$d->appendChild($e);
$d->loadXML($d->saveXML());
```

..you get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadXML(): Entity 'nbsp' not defined in Entity, line: 2 in php shell code on line 1
```

Why does this happen? Shoudn't `libxml` handle entities correctly?

Comment: btw, I'm only assuming this is an encoding problem, I really don't know what is going on

Comment: for what it's worth: `&#160;` is the equivalent XML entity

Comment: @oblig but how can i replace `&nbsp;` with `&#160;` without doing something awful like `str_replace`? Are there functions in php that help you with this stuff? Also, is `nbsp` the only one I'll have problems with?

Comment: @oblig what about this? `http://www.sourcerally.net/Scripts/39-Convert-HTML-Entities-to-XML-Entities` (I'd still love it if php did it for me)

Comment: Use a DTD which defines the necessary entities, or don't use those entities. Which is more work, or preferred, is entirely your decision to make. If you're fine with invalid XML, you can silence the error by using the `LIBXML_NOERROR` option on the `loadXML()` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `loadHTML()` instead since this entity is a HTML entity and not a generic XML entity.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php#89212

Comment: using `loadHTML` doesn't work because it doesn't recognize the `myelement` tag, I get `PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag myelement invalid in Entity, line: 2 in php shell code on line 1`

Comment: The link provided does show how you can add the entity to the doctype. Or you can create your own DTD if you have a specific spec in mind.